# How to create new Conda and .yml environment with updated Conda

Tags: python, conda, environment

Can't create  new conda or .yml environments from ananconda. Updated conda using

```
conda update --all
```

Updated to satisfy requirements of package I want to use (PyDESeq2). Before update I could create conda environments but received an error when attempting to create .yml environment. Now I can't even create a new conda environment.

Downloaded Repository from PyDESeq2 using

```
git clone https://github.com/owkin/PyDESeq2.git
```

Then attempted to create new conda version (per PyDESeq2 instructions) using

```
conda create env -f environment.yml
```

Received the following error:

```
usage: conda-script.py create [-h] [--clone ENV] (-n ENVIRONMENT | -p PATH) [-c CHANNEL] [--use-local] [--override-channels] [--repodata-fn REPODATA_FNS] [--strict-channel-priority] [--no-channel-priority]
                              [--no-deps | --only-deps] [--no-pin] [--copy] [--no-shortcuts] [-C] [-k] [--offline] [-d] [--json] [-q] [-v] [-y] [--download-only] [--show-channel-urls] [--file FILE]
                              [--no-default-packages] [--solver {classic} | --experimental-solver {classic}] [--dev]
                              [package_spec ...]
conda-script.py create: error: one of the arguments -n/--name -p/--prefix is required
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a typo in PyDESeq2 README. This should work.

```bash
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Comment: Yes, and seems [it is now corrected](https://github.com/owkin/PyDESeq2/commit/d5531157e8a1b41496178f06d063b270000bb359).

Comment: Thanks for catching this, and it does look like it is fixed on their github. Still having issues however, and get the following error: "EnvironmentFileNotFound: 'C:\Users\Murryadmin\environment.yml' file not found"

Comment: Probably you need to `cd PyDESeq2` to get into the directory where the `environment.yml` file is located